# Random main queue dispatches not received

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`from several background threads. However, it appears that occasionally the code in the dispatch block is not executed. Could this be because i dispatch asynchronously and the thread exits before the main queue can execute the code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting an NSLog in the beginning of your code snippet to be absolutely sure that it's not executing? Sometimes an if statement with faulty logic will pre-terminate your code. (From my past experience ;])

Answer (score 1):

The moment the dispatch_async() call returns, it's not important whether or not the thread that invoked it subsequently exits or not - the "request is in the system" so to speak!   Something else is happening in those "occasional" cases.  Does your program have a run loop or call dispatch_main() at the end of its main function?  Not clear whether this is a Cocoa/iOS/POSIX application you're describing.